# qpid Producer and Consumer on the same Session/Topic?

Tags: jms, qpid

Brocker C++ , Client java jms

It is correct to send a message to a topic and just after create a consumer on this Topic ?

```
connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
connection.start();
session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
topic = (Destination) context.lookup("topicSend");
Destination tempTopic = (Destination) context.lookup("topicSend");
MessageProducer messageProducer = session.createProducer(topic);
messageProducer.send(messageToSend);
```

... and just subsequent create a Consumer on the SAME Session and topic (topicSend is equal as tempTopic

```
MessageConsumer messageConsumer = session.createConsumer(tempTopic, MESSAGE_SELECTOR);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. That should be fine. Just be sure to close your producer if you're done with it.

Comment: ok, but the sent message will be received by the recipient and also by the current client that are sending ?

Comment: A topic subscriber won't get messages sent to the topic before it creates its subscription which appears to be the case in your example. In other words, the consumer created here *won't* get the message that is sent.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to use separate Session for producer  and consumer to avoid any issues.